# Evaluating $2+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2+\cdots}}$. Why can we say $2+\frac1x=x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continued-fractions

> The value of
> $$2+\dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{1}{2+\cdots}}$$ is ...
>
> (a) $1-\sqrt{2}\quad$ (b) $1+\sqrt{2}\quad$ (c) $1\pm\sqrt{2}\quad$ (d) None of these

Now I have some question here from the way I saw it solved online.

He took
$$2+ \frac1x = x$$

Now, my question is that why do we say $2+\frac1x$ equals to $x$? Like, it should be equal to $y$, right?

If we do that m it means we already know that RHS is $x$. I think that is wrong to do.

When we are not given like here nothing in RHS. Just "is" is written there. So what should we assume RHS as in these cases?

Answer for x = 1 + $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Try substituting the continued fraction in your question for $x$. You should see it produces a perfectly valid mathematical statement.

Comment: @Chubby Chef: *perfectly valid* --- This assumes that the continued fraction converges to a real number. For example, formally we have $2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + \ldots = 2(1 + 2 + 2^2 + \ldots),$ so putting $x = 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + \ldots$ gives $x = 2(1 + x),$ or $x = -2.$

Comment: @ChubbyChef i didn’t understand what you meant by your sentence. I understood from Daves answer

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro "This assumes that the continued fraction converges to a real number" ... **Right**.  However, what you have is a **simple** continued fraction (i.e. all numerators $= 1$ and all denominators $= 2 + $ an expression).  The machinery of continued fractions kicks in : the continued fraction **is** convergent.

Comment: But @DaveL.Renfro like you have 1+- in your example.I don’t think we need to do the same say in the question that I have right ?

Comment: @user279337,if  you assume the total quantity as $x$, then if you look at the thing below $1$, isn't it again the same quantity that you assumed as $x$?

Comment: This method of evaluating infinite series, infinite products, infinite roots, continued fractions, and other things is fairly commonly applied at the school mathematics level before having to deal with convergence (e.g. in a beginning algebra class when a linear equation is used to convert a repeating decimal to a quotient of integers, or sometimes in obtaining the geometric series sum formula), and I wasn't sure whether you were aware of the convergence issue, or if so, why it's such a major concern in more rigorous treatments of these things.

Comment: @user278337 You seem to be having a problem seeing it in the direction it is being explained, so try seeing that the result is correct by looking at it in the other direction. Give your continued fraction a name: $x$. Then take the inverse of $x$: $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{\text{continued fraction}}$. Now add $2$ to each side: $2+\frac{1}{x}=2+\frac{1}{\text{continued fraction}}$. But now $2+\frac{1}{x}$ equals something that looks just like $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that by some magic you have figured out the value of $x$. It's just a number. When you look at the first denominator in the expression you see exactly that expression again, so you can call it by the same name, $x$:
$$
x = 2 + \frac{1}{ x}
$$
and you can solve that equation for $x$.

The subtle problem with this argument is not that you used the same name $x$ twice, it's that you casually assumed that this expression that goes on forever actually makes sense. That assumption has to be justified - but not for this question. Since it's a multiple choice question the person who asked it is willing to assume the expression makes sense.

This kind of reasoning is common. For example, to express the number
$$
x = 0.131313\ldots
$$
as a fraction, you assume the infinite decimal makes sense. Then multiply by $100$ to see that
$$
100x = 13.1313\ldots = 13 + x.
$$
Solving for $x$ yields $13/99$.

In each of these examples what's hidden is justifying algebra in what looks like an infinite expression.

Comment: The infinite  series Include 2+1 , not just +1. It should be 2+$\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Well , I did not understand your 1st line.

Comment: Why is 2 + $\frac{1}{x}$= x and not some other variable ?

Comment: @user279337 See my edits in response to your comments. I reworked what was the first line into the second paragraph.

Comment: @user279337 First of all, one must establish that the (simple) continued fraction is convergent.  There is literature on simple continued fractions that establishes that.  Once that is established, then you can form a sequence $a_1 = 2$ and $a_{(n+1)} = 2 + \frac{1}{a_n}.$  Since the sequence is (assumed) convergent, you have that $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ are both converging to the **same value.**  However, you **also** have that if $a_n \to x$ then $a_{n+1} \to 2 + \frac{1}{x}.$  Therefore, one of the consequences of the sequence being convergent is that $x = 2 + \frac{1}{x}.$